# Would you replace an EGR or hose down the existing one with throttle body cleaner?

Tags: truck, ram, egr

I realize that some of this can be botttled down to *'how much down-time is it worth to me'* or *'what is the fastest way to fix a faulty EGR'* but that isn't my question. I can handle a day or two of downtime instead of an afternoon.

My Question:

How much better is a brand new EGR than the original that has been thoroughly bathed and cleaned with volatile chemicals and abrasive action (scrubbed with an old toothbrush)? Are there manufacturing tolerances that have been compromised that I may be overlooking by simply dissolving and removing build-up?

---

<sub>2007 Ram; 4.7L gas; 6 speed standard; 152K</sub>

Comment: Side note: a colleague replaced the EGR valve in a Skoda Octavia 1.9 PD (same as the VW diesel) with a "pattern" valve that was much cheaper than the genuine VW part. However, it failed quite soon.

Comment: New from the Dealer is always better than cleaned.